# How add markup and prefix / suffix for computed field

Tags: 7, entities

I want to add wrapper element to CCK computed field in a content type.

I could calculate the value of field but when I use HTML tags in Display Code section the result is not rendered properly.

for example I use this code in Display Code.

```
$display_output =  '<div class="row">' . $entity_field_item['value'] . ' <span class="suffix">Count</span></div>';
```

But the result is not corrected HTML . it seems it is encoded !!

```
&lt;div class=&quot;row&quot;&gt; &lt;span class=&quot;suffix&quot;&gt;Count&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Can you tell me what should I do to repair this problem ?

Comment: In which context is this output generated? Field output on node view, views template or custom template?

Comment: on node view. I tried to add markup on node view hook or page alter hook but I couldn't

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know where your variable `$entity_field_item` comes from, but you can generally add additional markup in at least three different ways:

**1. Adding `#prefix` and `#suffix` to the fields render array using a preprocess function:**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_myfield') {
    $variables['items'][0]['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">';
    $variables['items'][0]['#suffix'] = '<span class="suffix">Count</span></div>';
  }
}
```

**2. Adding `#prefix` and `#suffix` in `hook_node_view()`:**

```
$node->content['field_myfield'][0]['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">';
$node->content['field_myfield'][0]['#suffix'] = '<span class="suffix">Count</span></div>';
```

**3. Adding a new item to the `$content` array:**

```
$node->content['my_custom_output'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $entity_field_item['value'],
  '#prefix' => '<div class="row">',
  '#suffix' => '<span class="suffix">Count</span></div>',
);
```

Comment: I used node view hook and it seems it works. thanks a lot berliner

Answer (score 7):

## Drupal 8

This example simply creates a new markup object from the original text value:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__MYFIELD(&$variables) {

  $original_value = $variables['items'][0]['content']['#text'];
  $variables['items'][0]['content'] = Markup::create('<h1>' . $original_value . '</h1>');
}
```

You may want to check what's inside `$variables['items'][0]['content']` first. As it absolutely depends on the field type and its formatter where the original value can be found:

- maybe `$variables['items'][0]['content']['#text']`
- maybe `$variables['items'][0]['content']['#markup']`
- maybe `$variables['items'][0]['content']['#template']`
- ...

---

This example simply adds some markup on top of the field output:

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__MYFIELD(&$variables) {

  $variables['content']['#prefix'] = '<div class="linkbox-title"><span></span>' . t('Links') . '</div>';
}
```

---

This example wraps the output of every item of a multi-value field:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__MYFIELD(&$variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];
  $items = Element::children($element);

  foreach ($items as $key) {
    $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#prefix'] = '<div class="MYCLASS item-' . $key . '">';
    $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a preprocess function (which would be my choice), you will want to account for the possibility of more than one item in the field:

```
  function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_my_field'){
      foreach($variables['items'] as $key => $item){
        $variables['items'][ $key ]['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">';
        $variables['items'][ $key ]['#prefix'] = '<span class="suffix">Count</span></div>';
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. With the default computed field configuration on a new drupal install, all HTML markup is encoded and printed as clear text. i.e., instead of '**Hello World**' you get '`<b>Hello World</b>`'. This is because the default filter for computed fields in the CCK 'manage display' tab is set to 'plain text'. Change it to 'filtered markup' or 'unsanitized' (use with caution) to get the markup displayed.

Go to Structure => Content Types (your type with the computed field) => 'Manage Display'.

Make sure the display formatter is set to something other than 'plain text'. i.e. 'unsanitized' or 'filtered markup' generally works well for me.