# HTML tags removed during Views Rewriting

Tags: 7, views

Hello I created a sitemap with the modules "Views and data export". The sitemap of my page works fine, but I would add images to my page.

The sitemap should look at first capture, I do a test with figure and they are well placed. When I "rewrite the results" the tag is ignored.
How to implement these label ? it's been weeks since I'm on it.

Thank you

If I replace the HTML tags with text data it works:

[image]

However when I add HTML it gets removed:

[image]

---

I found answers to [How add markup and prefix / suffix for computed field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102347). Can you tell me how to put that in place?

Comment: I speak not of labels that are not displayed during rewriting. You see what I want to do? with capture

Comment: there is the same problem here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109079/show-field-label-when-using-tokens-in-global-custom-text-field-in-views#autocomment240223

Comment: and here https://www.drupal.org/node/1407906

Comment: I've updated your question, please have a look if this is what you mean.

Comment: yes, thank you for the update. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: I installed view php module but I do not know what to put in it.

Comment: @user60539 I answered the other question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109079/show-field-label-when-using-tokens-in-global-custom-text-field-in-views#autocomment240223

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: would you have a solution to this with the module view php

Comment: there is no solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML tags**, ugh, finally I understand your Q.

You can re-write your field using template files.

Go to `/sites/all/themes/YourTheme/templates` folder and

create **views-view-fields--[view-name]--[machine-name].tpl.php**

> For Example:
>
> If you view is called "Hello World" and the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg) is
>   block_1
>
> then it would be **views-view-fields--hello-world--block-1.tpl.php**

Inside your template file you put:

```
<?php

$fields["path"]->content = '<loc>' . $fields["path"]->content . '</loc>';

$fields["field_image"]->content = '<image:loc>' . $fields["field_image"]->content . '</image:loc>' . '<image:title>' . $fields["field_image-atl"]->content . '</image:title>';

echo $fields["path"]->content;
echo $fields["field_image"]->content;
```

When you are working with template files, **remember to clear/flush the cache** to see the changes.

Now your HTML tags should not get removed.

Comment: thank you for this information, but I have never done this. Can you give me more details on how to proceed? I posted a picture of the view in response