# The template of my views does not work

Tags: views

can you help me create a view template? Indeed when I rewrite the output field "image" no labels is displayed. So I created a "views-view-field--sitemap--page-6.tpl.php" template file in the folder of my theme, but I see no change. I emptied the cache.

```
<?php

$fields["path"]->content = '<loc>' . $fields["path"]->content . '</loc>';

$fields["field_image"]->content = '<image:loc>' . $fields["field_image"]->content . '</image:loc>' . '<image:title>' . $fields["field_image-atl"]->content . '</image:title>';

echo $fields["path"]->content;
echo $fields["field_image"]->content;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: To my template, I followed http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/html-tags-removed-during-views-rewriting/200390#200390

Comment: hi, no solution ?